# AngularJS filter expression object - logical OR

Tags: angularjs

I have an object, let's say like the following:

```
{
  a: 'abc',
  b: 'def',
  c: {
    x: 'xyz',
    y: 'klm'
  }
}
```

Now I want to programatically filter it by a query string, e.g. ("bc") for some of the object's properties, but not all. For instance, I only want "bc" to be matched against ".a" and ".c.x".

I've written a function that generates me an expression object (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) like this:

```
{
   a: 'bc',
   c: {
      x: 'bc' 
   }
}
```

This object (let's call it "expression") can then be passed to $filter like this:

```
$filter('filter')(arrayToSearchIn, expression);
```

My problem is, that I don't want AND matches, but OR ones, so the array should filter out object that contain "bc" in either ".a" or ".c.x", but not necessarily both. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle to check the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10200/